# I m creating an app using flutter in android studio. I created the registration form but when ever I press register button I show me some errors

Tags: flutter

int result = await Customer.registerCustomer(database, customer);
database.close();

```
  if (result > 0) {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context as BuildContext).showSnackBar(
      const SnackBar(content: Text('Registration successful')),
    );

    // Navigate to the welcome page
    Navigator.push(
      context as BuildContext,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const WelcomePage()),
    );
  } else {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context as BuildContext).showSnackBar(
      const SnackBar(content: Text('Registration failed')),
    );
```

i have tried everything in my book but its not working

Comment: please share what error is showing  and also inspect the `result` from the method  `Customer.registerCustomer`